# iOS Share Extension not presenting my custom ShareViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, share

I cant seem to present my custom ShareViewController. I inherited UIViewController, not SLComposeViewController, added it to the Storyboard, but when i select an image to share, ShareViewController is not presented. Here is my entire code:

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>

@interface ShareViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
@implementation ShareViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.alpha = 0;

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^
     {
         self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
     }];
}

- (void)dismiss
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.20 animations:^
     {
         self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, self.view.frame.size.height);
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:nil completionHandler:nil];
     }];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    for (NSItemProvider* itemProvider in ((NSExtensionItem*)self.extensionContext.inputItems[0]).attachments )
    {
        if([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:@"public.image"])
        {
            [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"public.image" options:nil completionHandler:
             ^(id<NSSecureCoding> item, NSError *error)
             {
                 UIImage *sharedImage = nil;
                 if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]])
                 {
                     sharedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)item]];


                 }
                 if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
                 {
                     sharedImage = (UIImage*)item;
                 }
             }];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Breakpoint indicates that runtime does execute the code, even grabs image, but the custom view controller is not presented for some reason. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was so stupid and it took me a while to figure it out, but for some reason, by default, custom ShareViewController view's background color is set to [UIColor clearColor]. Very stupid of Apple :), but i solved this case

Comment: Because of that I think : self.view.alpha = 0;

Comment: Yes I copied some code from some guy and didn't even noticed xD

Comment: :D often my problem too